# Are enum good to indicate object state?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

Lead developer in my current project forbid me to use any enums. He claims enums are just problems. I can use it only if I'm forced - when communicate with outside applications/libraries that require enum.
He tells that I should have object for every state. For example we have game with object Soldier. So I have to have objects:
- RunningSoldier
- SittingSoldier
- StandingSoldier

Is he right? I don't feel it. I have only arguments like I don't want to write so many classes.

Thanks!

Comment: did he explain why he thinks that enums are _problems_?

Comment: Sounds like he's a devout believer in the State design pattern. I see enumerations as a set of meaningful values and not necessarily a representation for the state of an object. In the case of your example, there can be benefits to using different classes as the different types of soldiers may have other aspects that rely on their current state which is exactly the rational for the State pattern.

Comment: As commonly used, enums are poorly typed. Use an algebraic data type instead.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO and opinion-based anyway. Whether introducing different classes for different states makes any sense, depends on how you intend to interact with your objects.

Comment: I use enums all the time and never had any problem with them.  Would be good to know and understand why he thinks they are just problems.

Comment: You can't change the type of an object. How are you going to transition the soldier between states?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. I usually start with `Enum`s as long as all I need is a single value. Once the state has other data associated with it (like cost, duration, etc.) then I convert to Classes. With Visual Studio, this refactoring is trivial. The time spent arguing about it, and the time spent creating classes until they are needed are both waste.

Comment: Such a general claim that 'enums are just problems' is nonsense. Enums are very helpful, just use them wisely. The enum could be a property in your entity that represents the state of that entity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your case enums are bad. Because I think RunningSoldier will have different properties/methods than other type of soldiers. If you will have an enum for the state, then in your every method you will have a if/else/switch condition. So your methods will be large and harder to maintain. So it is better to have different classes with a base Soldier class (OOP concepts).

**Update:**

If you need to add another type for soldier, then adding a class will be easier than enum. As for enum you have to go through all the methods (move, jump, fire, etc). But for class case it is easy to add a new class and implement those methods. Nice and easy.

It might be possible that in some other case enums will be better than separate classes. Like for example enum for CurrencyType or Units. I have a method in my code which takes two enums and converts value from one

```
public static double ConvertUnits(this double original, SimplifiedUnits sourceUnits, SimplifiedUnits targetUnits)
{
    if (sourceUnits == targetUnits || sourceUnits == SimplifiedUnits.Unknown)
    return original;
    if (sourceUnits == SimplifiedUnits.Feet && targetUnits == SimplifiedUnits.Meters)
    return original * GeometryConstants.MetersPerFoot;
    if (sourceUnits == SimplifiedUnits.Meters && targetUnits == SimplifiedUnits.Feet)
    return original / GeometryConstants.MetersPerFoot;
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Soldier was just an example. Are there situations where enums are better?

Comment: of course there are. For example you are opening a file, you can give specific enum(flag) there. Another example is enum for CurrencyType or Units.